# ReactJs/Gatsby with Clarifai on Netlify Error

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, netlify

"IT WORKS on my machine"...

It was the GATSBY_ENV_NAME_HERE not setup

Comment: Did you add the env to netlify?...

Comment: yes, i did add the env